# Use Twilio api 5.6.1 to retrieve all message logs in C#

Tags: c#, twilio

I need to retrieve all SMS logs from Twilio. The total number of record is expected to be large, aiming at around 100, 000 records. In previous library version, I can do the following to retrieve all the data:

```
//Set up twilio account
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
//Set up a request
var request = new MessageListRequest(); 
//Get sms logs based on the request filter
MessageResult messages = twilio.ListMessages(request);

//Loop through all the page uri by Twilio to retrieve the messages
while (messages.NextPageUri != null)
{
    if (messages.Messages != null)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    if (messages.NextPageUri != null)
    {
        messages = twilio.GetNextPage<MessageResult>(messages);
    }
}
```

How do I do the same with the current Twilio library version?

Comment: Did you look at the latest REST API docs? https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the current [Twilio REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message):

```
// Download the twilio-csharp library from twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp
using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;

class Example
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        const string authToken = "your_auth_token";
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var messages = MessageResource.Read();

        foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is embarrassing! As I first read the code my first instinct was that this shouldn't be this easy, and did not carefully read the document.